# How to select Image URL by not including "/"?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, regex-negation

I'm trying to figure out how to Series.str.extract() the image Urls (image-image-image.jpg) to a new column, but i'm having issues with the Regex. What am I doing wrong ?

**Here's how my data looks**

```
<a href="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image-image.image.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-11275" src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image-image.image-300x200.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200" /></a> <a href="https://kids-at-home.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image2-image2-image2.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-11271" src="https://kids-at-home.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image2-image2-image2.jpg-300x200.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200" />
```

I've tried excluding all the "/" from the matches and have a positive lookback for "/" so it starts there and a positive lookahead for "">" , but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Regexr, and my Jupyter Notebook, if the problem comes from there.

Here's my Regex code
r'^(?:(?!/).)*$(?<=/)(.*.jpg)(?=\">)'

I expected the regex match to be **image-image.image.jpg** and **image2-image2.image2.jpg** but it doesn't match anything.

**SOLVED REGEX CODE**

```
r'''(?<=/)([^/"']*\.jpe?g)(?=\"\>)"'''
```

Comment: Try `.str.extractall(r'''/([^/"']*\.jpg)"''')`

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i needed, i added a positive lookahead and lookback and the regex was perfect !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
df['col'].str.extractall(r'''/([^/"']*\.jpe?g)"''')
```

The `/([^/"']*\.jpg)"` pattern matches `/`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `/`, `"` and `'` and then `.jpg` / `.jpeg` and then just matches `"`.

Note that you do not need lookarounds because [`pandas.Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) only returns what was captured into Group 1 (or any capturing group in the pattern, but here, there is only 1 capturing group).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdGVrD/1), the result will only contain those green-highlighted parts. See also the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2F(%5B%5E%2F%22'%5D*%5C.jpe%3Fg)%22):

[image]

**Details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/"']*\.jpe?g)` - Group 1 (the output): any 0+ chars other than `/`, `"` and `'` and then `.jpeg` or `.jpg`
- `"` - a `"` char.

Answer (score 1):

A little more exhaustive solution:

```
https?:\/\/[A-z0-9-_.\/%]+\/([A-z0-9-_.%]+?\.(png|jpe?g|png))
```

It seems a bit scary but it is a little more verbose and supports encoded URLs too. You can find the name of your image in the first matched group($1).

Answer (score 0):

Here, we likely might not want to add start and end anchors, and we would be starting with a simple expression such as:

```
"https?.+?\.(jpg)"
```

If we wish to permit other extensions, such as `gif` or `png`, we can simply do so with logical ORs `|`:

```
"https?.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|png)"
```

If we wish to capture our URLs, we would simply add a capturing group:

```
"(https?.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|png))"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZMc5J/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\"(https?.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|png))\""

test_str = "<a href=\"https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image-image.image.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-11275\" src=\"https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image-image.image-300x200.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" /></a> <a href=\"https://kids-at-home.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image2-image2-image2.jpg\"><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-11271\" src=\"https://kids-at-home.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image2-image2-image2.jpg-300x200.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" />
"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, jex.im is a great tool ! I understand the syntax better now !